# Modify user to remove home directory

Tags: linux, arch-linux, passwd

The passwd file entry for a user associated with a service (squeezelite) indicates that user has a home directory (/home/squeezelite). This folder does not exist (and I suspect it never did).

The service is running fine, so my inclination is to modify the passwd file to indicate the user has no home directory. Is there some way to accomplish this with usermod or should I edit the passwd file directly? If the answer is to edit the passwd file, what change should I make? Replace `/home/squeezelite` with `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use @RalfFriedl's answer and use the `-d` option, which is used mostly with `/nonexistent` for that case, or you can edit the `/etc/passwd` file:

Just delete `/home/squeezelite`:
From something like:

```
squeezelite:x:1001:1001::/home/squeezelite:
```

You can either make it:

```
squeezelite:x:1001:1001:::
```

or

```
squeezelite:x:1001:1001::/nonexistent:
```

You can also use the root directory `/` for the home directory. However, my top suggestion is to just delete `/home/squeezelite` from the `passwd` file. Then the user will have no home directory.

Comment: Will specifying ``/nonexistent`` and ``/var/nonexistent`` satisfy ``shadow.service``, which is failing with ``user 'squeezelite': directory '/home/squeezelite' does not exist``.

Comment: @eponymous no, it will not. It will still say that the directory does not exist. That is why I suggest the first example, making it `squeezelite:x:1001:1001:::`

Comment: Interestingly, ``shadow.service`` objected to leaving the field blank, so I entered ``/``, which it accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I guess Arch doesn't accept that then. For me on Debian 9 it worked.

Answer (score 2):

From `man usermod`

> -d, --home HOME_DIR
>
> The user's new login directory.

If the old home didn't matter, the new home probably also wouldn't matter, but you could use something like `/var/nonexistent` to show that the home directory is not needed or supposed to exist.